# How do I sum a CSV column with positive and negative values in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
Name  Balance
----  -------
Tom   (0.09) 
Dick  600.5  
Harry (0.13) 
Sally 5.25
```

When I import the CSV (see above data) using `Import-Csv`, the "Balance" column imports as a string and I can't do any math on it.  Note: The ( ) surrounded values are negatives.
HELP!

`$csv = Import-Csv -Path $file | select -Property 'Name','Balance'`

```
$csv | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
Balance     NoteProperty string Balance=(0.09)         
Name        NoteProperty string Name=Tom
```

Comment: You can convert the strings into decimales or doubles without any issues after importing your Csv but it's not clear what do you mean by values between parentheses being negatives. you could try with `$csv.ForEach({ $_.Balance = $_.Balance -replace '\(([\d.]+)\)', '-$1' -as [double] })` then the values would be actual doubles you can do math on

Comment: PowerShell can convert it for you as long as you rid the string of parenthesis: `($csv.balance -replace "\(|\)","" | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum`.

Comment: Tom's balance is -0.09, but the CSV has it as (0.09) as it's an accounting export that's out of my control.  It's pretty standard.  So the "total" of the Balances should result in 605.53.

Comment: In that case, swap the RegEx in my example for the one provided by @SantiagoSquarzon and it should give you just that.

Comment: So the `-as` in the same line was removing some of the values, I did it seperately after simplifying the `-replace` with just  `$csv.ForEach({ $_.Balance = $_.Balance -replace '\(', '-'  -replace'\)',''  })`  seemed to do the trick.  The script came out great.  Thanks again all!

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the property values of the imported Csv are of the type `string`, you can however reassign them to the desired type without any problem. For this you can use the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-regular-expressions) to replace the parentheses with the minus sign `-` and the [`-as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) to safely convert the `strings` into `double` or `decimal`.

Assuming the imported Csv is stored in the `$csv` variable:

```
$csv = Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv
$csv.ForEach({
    $_.Balance = $_.Balance -replace '\(([\d.]+)\)', '-$1' -as [decimal]
})
[Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([decimal[]] $csv.Balance) # => 605.53
```

`Decimal` is the recommended struct for dealing with currency values as [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) notes in his helpful comment.

From [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> The [Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0) value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors.

Comment: You might want to use ```[decimal]``` instead of ```[double]``` for currency values...

Comment: @mclayton good point. thanks!